How do I merge multiple poetry.lock files together without upgrading dependency versions?
I have a few related Poetry projects. Each is a microservice, and they form an application together. They all get updated together and use the same versions of dependencies. A lot of the build-related code and scripts is duplicated over the projects, with small variations between them. i.e. The worst kind duplication. Recently it was decided that having them be separate git and python projects wasn't a good idea, and they should be merged into a single project (which still deploys as multiple microservices). I had a look into having nested pyproject projects, but that doesn't seem to be supported, so a single pyproject.toml it is.
All projects have compatible dependency versions. Merging the pyproject.toml files is pretty straightforward, but how do I merge the poetry.lock files? I don't want to complicate the merge by also updating all dependency versions.

Merging poetry.lock files is actually not that difficult. Don't try to do it manually, they are not meant to be human edited and it will be a lot of pain. Follow these steps:

Create a new directory outside of your projects, so that Poetry will create a new environment for it when you run it.
Copy the pyproject.toml and poetry.lock files of the first project to the new directory.
Run poetry install --no-root --no-directory in the new directory. That will install only the external dependencies for the first project into the new environment.
Repeat steps 2 and 3 for the other poetry projects.
Remove the pyproject.toml and poetry.lock files, and put the merged pyproject.toml file in the directory. I'll assume you have a manually merged pyproject.toml file ready.
Run poetry lock --no-upgrade, and it will create the merged poetry.lock file for you.

If your dependencies in the poetry.lock files are not actually 100% compatible, the last installed project will win and it will downgrade any dependencies in the new environment. So in that case you can install the projects in order of priority. If you don't want the versions from one project to win, but you want to pick and choose, you can edit the merged project to pin the dependency versions you want using poetry add package@x.y.z, before running poetry lock --no-upgrade. After locking, remove the unneeded version pin from the pyproject.toml again.
